# dlib build fail, cannot import dlib

Tags: python, c++, dlib, cloud9

I'm trying to install dlib onto cloud9, but I keep getting this error.

```
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/src/face_recognition.cpp.o] Error 4
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: cmake build failed!
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: how much RAM do you have? looks like you need to add swapfile or add RAM

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time for this question, I faced the same issue and hopefully, this will help someone else.
it seems that you are running out of RAM memory, so you can fix it by swapfile based on this [answer](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/issues/224#issuecomment-354434754) as below

```
free
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.img bs=1024k count=1000
sudo mkswap /var/swap.img
sudo swapon /var/swap.img
free
```